# What will happen if I accidentally connect GND to VCC and VCC to GND?

Tags: gpio, dht22, rip

I accidentally connected DHT11's GND to VCC and VCC to GND. Now I can't read using it. Is it damaged now? What could have happened? (Sorry if it sounds lame, I am a newbie)

Comment: This parrot is no more! He has ceased to be! 'E's expired and gone to meet 'is maker!

Comment: In other words, without testing its probably as dead as a dead parrot (@Ghanima's source: https://youtu.be/4vuW6tQ0218 ). Unless its resting... (sorry for the jokes) -  anyway, what did you actually do?

Comment: Wasn't sure about the front side of the DHT11.. lol and interchanged the position twice or thrice and now it won't work. Time to return the dead parrot to Amazon ;)

Comment: I've heard of people killing DHT11s this way before, so it is probably broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the time, in any device without a polyfuse, connecting power directly to ground will damage and usually brick the device. So, in short, I doubt it will ever work again.

---

R.I.P. @Ric's DHT11 it will be missed.